# The meaning of を in あなたは何をしていますか?

Tags: particle-を, questions

What is the function of を in the sentence:

```
あなたは何をしていますか?
```

Why can't it be written without it, like:

```
あなたは何していますか?
```

Answer (score 1):

'[を](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%92)' is a particle that is used mainly as an *object particle* to

> indicate a **direct object** of action.

Therefore, it needs to be used as you are asking what the object of *doing* is in the question.

> I am doing my homework.

could be translated to

> [宿題]{しゅくだい}**を**しています.

In formal Japanese, it is better not to omit 'を' in the sentence.

Comment: Without the particle, you would sound like Tarzan. "Tarzan hungry!"

Comment: @kurakura88 Or probably impolite as in "何していますか?"