# What is 発表待つ saying in this title?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading some practice articles written in Japanese; not sure if they're based on real articles, but no matter.

The title in question is 村上ファン集うカフェで発表待つイベント, and I'm not 100% sure
 what the 発表待つ part is saying, thus I thought I'd ask.

It looks grammatically incorrect to mean, and I'm not sure what the title is saying as a result of this.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23785/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14559/9831 -- Particles, most significantly は, を and が, are omitted in article headlines. It's one of the typical characteristics of headline grammar.

Comment: Really? Near! Thx, lad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I found a cached version of the article.](http://archive.fo/OfeCa)

In the text, there is

> **発表**の瞬間**を待つ**イベントが開かれました。

From this, you can guess that the particle を is omitted from the title. I think linguists call the practice of omitting words like this [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Here is another question about omitting を: [The meaning of を in あなたは何をしていますか?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38447/the-meaning-of-%E3%82%92-in-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B/38449)

In fact, a whole lot of other particles are also omitted from the title. I'll mark the particles with **bold**.

> 村上**の**ファン**が**集うカフェで発表**を**待つイベント

Literal translation:

> [At]{で} the café [where]{が} Murakami['s]{の} fans gather, the event of waiting [for]{を} the release

Comment: I'll never get used to particle omitting...

Comment: @Tirous It will get easier once you read enough. But I had problems with that title as well :D